# How to find the calling viewController in my stack?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an application with a two storyboards, one tab bar controller and 6+ viewControllers embedded in their own navigationControllers.

I present CartViewController modally from a barButtonItem in all VC's, and from the cart I present CustomersVC from a tableViewCell. My problem is that when I present Customers from the Cart, I can then again go to the Cart from the CustomersVC and then just keep going in loop..

#### Assumption

My assumption is that if i present Cart modally from anyVC, then present a navigationController modally from cart, which then presents CustomersVC, an array would like this would exists:

1. Any viewController
2. CartViewController
3. CustomersNavigationController
4. CustomersViewController

To fix this I'm attemting to remove the "ViewCart" barButtonItem from customersVC IF it is called from the cart. My problem is that I can't manage to traverse the stack to check it out. I've tried out several methods found here at SO, but none works.

I know I can use a delegate and set a variable to show/hide the button, but I'm eager to learn and would also like it to be more robust instead of having to remember to set and reset the var manually.

Any suggestions?

#### Code

```swift
extension UIViewController {
    @objc func viewCart() {
        if Cart.sharedInstance.order.items.count != 0 {

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Cart", bundle: nil)
            if let cartVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Cart") as? CartViewController {
                let cartNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: cartVC)
                self.present(cartNavigationController, animated: true)
            }
        }
    }
}

Class CartViewController {

  let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
   if let customersNC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CustomersNC") as? UINavigationController {
   present(customersNC, animated: true)

}


class CustomersTableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {

// Tried presentingViewController:

    if let CartVC = presentingViewController as? CartViewController {
        myButton.isEnabled = false
    }

// Tried navigationController?.viewControllers:

        guard let controllersInStack = navigationController?.viewControllers else { return }
        if let CartVC controllersInStack.first(where: { $0 is CartViewController }) as? CartViewController  {
            myButton.isEnabled = false
        }

// Tried an extension I found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38583941/get-all-list-of-uiviewcontrollers-in-ios-swift, but it returns nil

extension UIViewController {
   /**
    * Traverses the entire VC hirearchy downwards and collects VC'w that are of speccific PARAM: type
    * - Fixme: ⚠️️ this can be written more elegantly with flatMap
    * ## Example:
    * let vc: CustomVC? = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window?.rootViewController?.descendants().first
    */
   func descendants<T>(type: T.Type? = nil) -> [T] {
       var childrenOfType: [T] = []
       self.children.forEach {
           if let child: T = ($0 as? T) {
               childrenOfType.append(child)
           }
           if !$0.children.isEmpty {
               childrenOfType += $0.descendants(type: type)
           }
       }
       return childrenOfType
   }
}
```

Comment: There is no such array so your assumption is false. Instead of making a false assumption, concentrate on the reality of the problem. From what you've said so far, it sounds like it would be sufficient to ask whether there is a `navigationController`. But if would help me give a better answer if you would draw a better diagram of the situation, i.e. show the _entire_ view controller hierarchy as it stands at the moment when you would like to be able to say "go no deeper", with complete info at every step as to what we did to get here (child, push, or present).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every view controller has either a `parent` or a `presentingViewController` (or both), so by asking for these, you can figure out "where you are".

That will usually be sufficient to tell you the situation, especially if you use class types judiciously (for example, you can make your navigation controllers different UINavigationController subclasses just for the sake of knowing where you are later).

If you want a complete conspectus of the view controller chain to where you are, you can trace your way up through the chain recursively, like this:

```
func trace(_ vc: UIViewController) {
    print(vc)
    if let parent = vc.parent {
        print("parent:")
        trace(parent)
        return
    }
    if let presenter = vc.presentingViewController {
        print("presenter:")
        trace(presenter)
        return
    }
    print("done")
}
```

That example prints rather than accumulating a list of view controllers along with the nature of the connection between each of them (which is what you really need), but by calling it from the "last" view controller in the chain, you can get a mental picture of what the chain must look like at the point where you want to say "go no deeper".

Here's a more complete example that shows how to accumulate a backward trace into an array:

```
class MyVC: UIViewController {
    func makeTrace() {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let result = self.trace([(.start, self)])
        print(result)
    }
    enum Link: String {
        case parent
        case presenter
        case start
    }
    typealias Chain = [(Link, UIViewController)]
    func trace(_ chain: Chain) -> Chain {
        if let parent = chain.last!.1.parent {
            return trace(chain + [(.parent, parent)])
        }
        if let presenter = chain.last!.1.presentingViewController {
            return trace(chain + [(.presenter, presenter)])
        }
        return chain
    }
}
```

So `result` will tell you enough to know "where you are".